# How to get PR in France or any European country as gay couple?

Tags: schengen, europe, france

I’m Sri Lankan male and gay. I need to get married to my boyfriend. Since gay marriages are not legal in Sri Lanka, how to het married in another country and live in there?

Please help.

Comment: In most U.S. states, non-citizens can marry each other as long as they have lived there (in many states, they need to live there for only one day). Try Las Vegas, Nevada; it is known for a popular "marriage tourism" destination. Moreover, all U.S. states recognize same-sex marriage.

Comment: What do you mean by "PR"?

Comment: @DavidRicherby permanent residence.

Comment: The answer depends significantly on the nationality of your boyfriend.  Is he also Sri Lankan?  But since you want to *move* to another country, you should ask at [Expatriates.SE] rather than here.

Comment: @MarkPerryman That is not at all true. Many countries offer visas explicitly for non-residents to get married (and then leave).

Answer (score 1):

Most countries doesn't grant people permission to live there solely because their sexual orientation doesn't allowed them to get married where they come from. Risk of prosecution due to sexual orientation is a factor considered where granting/rejecting an application for asylum, but it doesn't sound like that's your situation.

In some (most?) countries both people involved would have to be citizens, others might be satisfied if you can convince the local authorities that none of the involved are already married.

In some countries you can get married either in a church or at city hall (or where ever the local authorities do that), most churches probably require some form of association and have procedures that take a lot long, so don't dream about that.

If you (and your partner) want to go to France (or anywhere else in Europe), apply for a visa. If you get it you can then try to research whether you can get married while away.

And if you (and our partner) actually wants to migrate and live in another country. travel.SE is *not* the site, expatriates.SE is a better option.